# Redirect ALL PAGES to https

Tags: .htaccess

I'm using the code below in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://domain.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

It won't redirect all my pages to `https` but only the homepage. If i access `domain.com/example-page` it's not redirecting to https://domain.com/example-page.

How can i fix this? I searched a lot of topics, there are a lot of "solutions" but none of them work... Thank you!

Comment: In my opinion, this is the wrong Stack site for such a question. I think this should be moved to Server Fault or Super User.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
```

It works. It's tested.